# NoClassDefFoundError even though the JAR's are included in Manifest Class-Path

Tags: java, jar

Following is the manifest file of a jar I created.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Arun
Class-Path: lib/httpclient-4.5.1.jar lib/httpcore-4.4.3.jar lib/c
 ommons-logging-1.2.jar lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar lib/httpmime-4.5.1.j
 ar lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar lib/junit-4.10.jar lib/hamcrest-core-1.1
 .jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_72
Main-Class: org.wso2.ml.driver.Shell
```

Although the Class-Path entry shows that it has added necessary jars in the lib folder of the jar, when I run this executable jar I get a Noclassdeffound error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ContentBody
```

This is how I execute my jar

```
java -jar restclient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: The JVM doesn't agree with you - it can't find the class.  You need to figure out what you did wrong and not insist that all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although the Class-Path entry shows that it has added necessary jars in the lib folder of the jar

Java doesn't look for jar files **inside** your jar file. It looks for them **next to** the jar. So you need this file/directory structure:

```
restclient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
lib/
  httpclient-4.5.1.jar 
  httpcore-4.4.3.jar
  ...
```

Also, having junit and hamcrest in your runtime dependencies doesn't seem right. Those should be used by test code, not production code.

Comment: Well that solved the issue. But i do not know how junit and hamcrest ended up in the lib folder. I have not inlcuded those dependencies directly in my pom.xml

Comment: is there a way that i could find out how those jars ended up in here?

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` should give you the dependency tree, and allow find where they come from.

Comment: <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
<artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>  is what has included those two jars. Do i have to get rid of those two jars?

Comment: You could add an exclusion in your pom, yes. Unless json-simple really needs them at runtime, which I would found quite dubious.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the mistake is the assumption you seem to be making:

> Although the Class-Path entry shows that it has added necessary jars in the lib folder **of the jar**,

I am assuming that you have put these `Class-Path` JAR's in the `restclient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` itself for otherwise you'd not be having this problem.

If you see the [JAR file tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html), it clearly mentions the following:

> Note: The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over Internet protocols. To load classes in JAR files within a JAR file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those classes. For example, if MyJar.jar contains another JAR file called MyUtils.jar, you cannot use the Class-Path header in MyJar.jar's manifest to load classes in MyUtils.jar into the class path.

You should make those other JAR files available on a local folder. If you like Maven, perhaps consider using the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html).